# How to host a webpage with AWS using IP address

Tags: apache, server, ip-address, amazon-ec2

I have a free tier AWS server. It is a Ubuntu server and I a beginner. I don't have a registered domain name, I have HTML and CSS code for the web pages.

I normally see that I can access websites using their registered IP addresses. How do I deploy my HTML code so it becomes a public website that can be accessed through the IP address that Amazon has provided?

Note I haven't yet installed Apache as I have not figured out what I should do with it. It would be great if someone can direct me to on how to make the HTML code public where anyone can view it using the IP address.

Comment: You can't use the IP address on AWS

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ayCfB    .....this is the IP on my ec2 instance and I know a website that runs on ec2 and can be accessed through its IP.

Comment: You can't rely on IP addresses in AWS because that instance my not exist five minutes from now.

Comment: AWS calls has "elastic IP addresses" that can be reserved and moved between instances within AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every AWS EC2 instance should have a "Public DNS (IPv4)" address available in the AWS EC2 Control Panel - something like:

`ec2-1-2-3-4.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

where the IP address is part of it (the sample is equivalent to IP 1.2.3.4).

You can use that to directly access the web site, and you can also use it as a CNAME record if you want to use it for a domain/subdomain registered elsewhere.

Setting up Apache, etc. is not too hard - Google: AWS Ubuntu Apache and you should be able to get the answers to that part.